# Edge Loops Not Working

Tags: modeling

hoping you folks can help.

In Blender 2.82a(2.82.7) edge loops seems to neither work with Alt+LMB, or double click or even going to Select->Loops->Edge Loops.

On the other hand Edger Rings is working fine.

Has anybody else gotten this issue?

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Can you share an example file? Edge loops behave *very* differently in different situations.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Did it work in previous versions? Are you on Linux by any chance?

Comment: Hello you two, thanks for replying. I'm running on Windows 10, and sorry, but I don't know how to ember a pic into this thread, but I can tell you that it edge loops doesn't even on a newly generated cube primitive that's had no modification done to it. I've now tried it on two different PC's, both running windows 10, with the same results.

Comment: A cube doesn't really have edge loops. Did you try on a UV sphere? Also, isn't the shortcut Alt+Shift+RMB ?

Comment: Same thing here, sort of...but won't work on Linux.
Blender 2.82a: Alt-LMB does not work for 'Loop Select' on Linux Mint nor Linux Ubuntu. Also, does not work from the 'Select>Select Loops>Edge Loops' menu. Tested on Torus and UV sphere. Two different PC's. Does work on Windows 10 however. All new installs of Blender with factory defaults. No preferences modified, no emulations, etc.
Also tried with 2.83beta. Same results. No go on Linux, works on Windows10.